# MongoDB: Error “Cannot use a session that has ended” when inserting into a collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Started using mongoDB today and used the sample code to first connect to a existing database and then add a new object into my collection:

```
//jshint esversion:6
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

// Replace the uri string with your connection string.
const uri =
  "mongodb://localhost:27017";

const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function run() {
  try {
    const database = client.db('shopDB');
    const products = database.collection('products');

    // Query for a movie that has the title 'Back to the Future'
    const query = { id: 1 };
    const product = await products.findOne(query);
    console.log(product);

    //insert a new products
    var newProduct = {id: 5, name: 'Cat', price: 10, stock: 0};
    products.insertOne(newProduct, async function(err, res){
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('1 product created');
    })
  } finally {
   await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

If I execut the above code I get: **Error “Cannot use a session that has ended” when inserting into a collection** I assume it is because of the `await client.close();` because if add this command to the callback func of my insertOne() func it works fine.

But if the command is in **finally** shouldn't the connection be terminated at the end of the function run()? Why is the session ended before I could insert my object?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are not awaiting for the insert and you code goes straight to finally to close the connection before the insert executes

```
await products.insertOne(newProduct)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think in general I have to learn more about async functions. I thought, that first everything in "try" will be executed and then it jumps into "finally". But th is is wrong, right?